# Converting date to timestamp based on timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone, imap

I'm fetching emails using PHP Imap and this is an example of an object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [subject] => Email Subject
            [from] => Sender <sender@domain.com>
            [to] => me@domain.com
            [date] => Sat, 19 Aug 2017 20:09:33 +1000
            [message_id] => <80d657c74967c8dc56138ca9552f0a2e@anyweb.apca.local>
            [size] => 1881518
            [uid] => 703
            [msgno] => 527
            [recent] => 0
            [flagged] => 0
            [answered] => 0
            [deleted] => 0
            [seen] => 0
            [draft] => 0
            [udate] => 1503137430
        )

)
```

Although I do have a `udate` but I wanted to double check if matches my timezone, so I did:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$str = 'Sat, 19 Aug 2017 20:09:33 +1000';
echo strtotime($str); // 1503137373 ??
```

Even tried:

```
$date = new DateTime($str, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
echo $timestamp; // 1503137373 ??
```

So in both cases I get a timestamp that doesn't match the one thats fetched from the mail server, what am I missing here?

Comment: timestamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. so your database mail sent time and the current time will never be the same

Comment: if you can get timezone from database than your problem is solved

Comment: So they are about one minute off? ...430 and ....373. that is not a timezone. Could it be time sent and time received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
   echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
   echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- udate - labeled by a mailserver
- Date, date - labeled by a client

> The difference between 'date' and 'udate' seems to be rather more than
> just the way they're formatted.
>
> 'date' is the date that was written in the headers by the sender's
> mail client, and probably bears little to do with reality. It's
> dependent on your sender knowing what the correct time is; it could be
> out by a few minutes, days, months or even years.
>
> 'udate' is the real date that the e-mail hit your IMAP server.
>
> Use 'udate' if you want to do neat stuff like work out how much e-mail
> you get sent on a daily basis - or, as I do, how much spam I get.

http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.imap-headerinfo.php.htm

---

From [here](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/function.imap-headerinfo.html):

> date - The message date as found in its headers
>
> Date - Same as date
>
> udate - mail message date in Unix time